# Run `create-react-app` from within Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Assuming that a local system has `create-react-app` installed (`npm i -g create-react-app`), I want to run it with parameters from within a Common Lisp file. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: To run programs synchronously or asynchronously: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/os.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as i know, the potrable solution is [uiop:run-program](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/uiop.html#UIOP_002fRUN_002dPROGRAM), since your cl distribution probably has the `asdf` included.

```
CL-USER> (uiop:run-program "create-react-app" :output t :error-output t)
;;Please specify the project directory:
;;  create-react-app <project-directory>

;;For example:
;;  create-react-app my-react-app

;;Run create-react-app --help to see all options.
;;; Debugger entered on #<UIOP/RUN-PROGRAM:SUBPROCESS-ERROR {10018B83A3}>
```

this one reports error, as the `create-react-app` itself does for no args.

```
(uiop:run-program "create-react-app my-new-shiny-app" :output t :error-output t)
```

succeeds, and creates app in your cwd.

you can wrap it into a function like this, for example:

```
(defun create-react-app (app-path &key verbose info scripts-version template use-npm use-pnp typescript)
  (let ((cmd (format nil "create-react-app ~a ~
                            ~@[--verbose~*~] ~
                            ~@[--info~*~] ~
                            ~@[--scripts-version ~a~] ~
                            ~@[--template ~a~] ~
                            ~@[--use-npm~*~] ~
                            ~@[--use-pnp~*~] ~
                            ~@[--typescript~*~]"
                     app-path verbose info scripts-version template use-npm use-pnp typescript)))
    (format t "executing shell command: ~a~%" cmd)
    (uiop:run-program cmd :output t :error-output t)))

(create-react-app "my-new-shiny-app" :template "cra-template-quickstart-redux" :use-npm t)
```

havent thoroughly tested it, but it should work.

Comment: I like that you are using mine cra-template ^_^